# Rice water ? Spoiled?

Tags: rice, water

I came across this beauty hack using rice water as the core ingredient. I soaked rice in water COVERING IT WITH A PLASTIC BAG (ORDINARY SHOPPING BAG) left it for one day at room temperature and today when I removed the shopping bag it smelt kinda bad. I was gona use it as a face mask... but now im sure weather to use it or not?  So is it spoiled?  Also do you have any suggestion how do not I spoil it  I.e  maybe 
1.wrapping with the plastic bag was a bad idea...or
2.shouldn't have left it at room temp?
3.or any other suggestion?

Comment: You might want to have a look at our generic posts on [shelf life](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/how-long-can-i-store-a-food-in-the-pantry-refrigerator-or-freezer) and [refrigeration](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34670/how-do-i-know-if-food-left-at-room-temperature-is-still-safe-to-eat). And yes, if it smells bad, dump it.

Comment: I'm wavering - you stating that you want to use the rice water on your skin for a beauty procedure is clearly off-topic here. Yet I can imagine other posters wanting to *consume* the water from soaking rice. For now, I have to vote to close this question, but if you could [edit] your post for [some kind of use we address here](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), I'll be happy to retract my close vote or vote for re-opening. Please take the [tour] and browse our [help] to learn more about the site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as it stands, it's not about food, but about food items as cosmetics.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it would be safer to discard the rice and water. Rice has a tendency to ferment.

I would wash & drain the rice at least once, as there can be traces of husk, talc and any other unwanted dirt/impurities. If you soak the rice for long periods of time, depending on the humidity and temperature of where you are soaking your rice, you may place this in a cool shaded place, or place in the refrigerator as the temperature is regulated.

Alternatively you could consider substituting rice flour instead of rice grains.  Note: This could also ferment, but may reduce the required soaking time.